# How to handle characters that need UTF-8 on XML retrieved from HTTP GET on powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am not able to retrieve data under UTF-8 encoding, through a HTTP GET request on powershell.

Code:

```
$headers_tables=@{}
$headers_tables.Add("content-type", "application/xml; charset=utf-8")
$xml_employee_future_jobinfo = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url_employee_future_jobinfo -Method GET -Headers $headers_tables
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<table>
 <row id="2968" employeeId="839">
  <field id="date">2022-11-28</field>
  <field id="location">X</field>
  <field id="department">D</field>
  <field id="division">Infrastructure &amp; IT</field>
  <field id="jobTitle">Z</field>
  <field id="reportsTo">X Poli??ski</field>
 </row>
</table>
```

If I open this API link on a browser I am able to see that XML as expected, with special characters and accents.

How can I solve this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the away that I've found to be able to handle that XML, exporting it to a file, and read it under UTF-8:

```
$headers_tables=@{}
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url_employee_future_jobinfo -Method GET -Headers $headers_tables -OutFile "C:\Scripts\Power_Automate\xmldump_jobinfo.xml"
[xml]$xml_employee_future_jobinfo = get-content "C:\Scripts\Power_Automate\xmldump_jobinfo.xml" -Encoding "utf8"
Write-Host "XML: "
$xml_employee_future_jobinfo.table.row.field
```

Output:

```
id         #text              
--         -----              
date       2022-11-28         
location   X
department D
division   Infrastructure & IT
jobTitle   Z    
reportsTo  X Poliński
```